# Unique Key created only when breakpoint is set, otherwise key is replicated

Tags: c#

So, I'm sure there is a simple explanation for this but I've only been working with C# for a few months now so I still have a lot to learn.

I was just working on a little app that generates a set of unique keys, just some basic skills building stuff.

I'm running into this issue where if I set a break point at `keyList.Add(sb.ToString());` and F5 through all iterations I get a list of keys and all have unique values, but if I remove the breakpoint and just run the solution it just repeats the same key.

Can someone please explain why this is happening? Does it have something to do with the `Random()` or my placement of the `StreamWriter`?

```
public class KeyCreator
{
    public static void alphaList()
    {
        string lowerAlpha = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z";
        string upperAlpha = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z";
        SortedList<string, string> alphaList = new SortedList<string, string>();
        string[] splitListLower = lowerAlpha.Split(',');
        string[] splitListUpper = upperAlpha.Split(',');
        for (int i = 0; i < splitListLower.Length; i++)
        {
            alphaList.Add(splitListLower[i], splitListUpper[i]);
        }
        numberGen(alphaList);
    }

    public static void numberGen(SortedList<string, string> alphaList)
    {
        List<string> keyList = new List<string>();
        for (int b = 0; b < 20; b++)
        {
            int max = alphaList.Count;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                int upperLower = rnd.Next(0, 10);
                if (upperLower < 5)
                {
                    for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++)
                    {
                        int lowerUpper = rnd.Next(0, 10);
                        if (lowerUpper < 4)
                        {
                            int index = rnd.Next(0, max);
                            sb.Append(alphaList.Keys[index]);
                        }
                        else if (lowerUpper > 3 && lowerUpper < 7)
                        {
                            int index = rnd.Next(0, max);
                            sb.Append(alphaList.Values[index]);
                        }
                        else if (lowerUpper > 6)
                        {
                            int rand = rnd.Next(0, 9);
                            sb.Append(rand);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (upperLower > 4)
                {
                    for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++)
                    {
                        int lowerUpper = rnd.Next(0, 10);
                        if (lowerUpper < 4)
                        {
                            int index = rnd.Next(0, max);
                            sb.Append(alphaList.Keys[index]);
                        }
                        else if (lowerUpper > 3 && lowerUpper < 7)
                        {
                            int index = rnd.Next(0, max);
                            sb.Append(alphaList.Values[index]);
                        }
                        else if (lowerUpper > 6)
                        {
                            int rand = rnd.Next(0, 9);
                            sb.Append(rand);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (i < 3)
                {
                    sb.Append("-");
                }
            }
            keyList.Add(sb.ToString());
        }
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\keys.txt"))
        {
            foreach (string key in keyList)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't create a `Random` inside a loop, create it once, use it again and again and again.

Comment: Ron is correct, this is why you're getting the same value. To expand, the parameterless Random constructor `Random()` uses the system clock as its seed. By creating a new `Random` object in a loop, the system clock might not have changed, so the seed is the same and therefore, since the algorithm is deterministic, the value outputted is the same.

Comment: There is a *very* canonical explanation of this concept here: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx

Comment: Very interesting, I will read up on this, thanks for the input guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is this:

```
public static void numberGen(SortedList<string, string> alphaList)
{
    List<string> keyList = new List<string>();
    for (int b = 0; b < 20; b++)
    {
        int max = alphaList.Count;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();   //<-- This line is the problem
```

`Random` is by default seeded with the current date/time. Since the accuracy of `DateTime` isn't all that great, you are creating the same random numbers over and over again. It works when you break in the debugger because you pause long enough for the `DateTime` to change sufficiently to create a new seed for `Random`.

The solution is to do this:

```
[ThreadStatic]
static Random rnd = new Random();
public static void numberGen(SortedList<string, string> alphaList)
{
    //This if is required because it can be null on subsequent threads.
    if (rnd == null) rnd = new Random();
    List<string> keyList = new List<string>();
    for (int b = 0; b < 20; b++)
    {
        int max = alphaList.Count;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

Move the creation outside the loop and use the same instance.

Also, as Scott Chamberlain noted in the comments, `Random` isn't thread-safe and static methods should be, so I added the [`[ThreadStatic]` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to avoid needing to `lock` around each `Next` call. Not doing this and calling it from multiple threads can cause the `Random` state to get corrupted and return all zeros.

Comment: I would be careful with your "solution", `Random` is not thread safe so if two functions call `numberGen` at the same time you can easily get corrupted state. It would be better to pass the Random in or else you need to lock around every `rnd.Next` call. If this was not a static method I would not have said any thing, but generally static methods are supposed to be safe to be called by multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Good catch, I edited the answer to reflect something that is more thread safe.